# Namespace semantic differences

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I see most of the types in `.NET framework` are spread across 3 different namespaces (may be more), one start with `Microsoft`, other with `System` and the third with `Windows`.

For example there is `Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool` and `System.Threading.ThreadPool`.

Is there a clear cut semantic difference on this design?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Microsoft.*` namespaces are typically .NET namespaces for features which are specific to Windows, e.g. registry access

`System.*` namespaces are "normal" .NET system namespaces

`Windows.*` namespaces are typically part of Windows Runtime aka WinRT (for Windows 8 store apps, Windows Phone 8)

Answer (score 6):

`Windows`, is for  **Windows8** family SDK.

`System` is for common .NET namespases.

`Microsoft` is for some windows specific OS features.

Answer (score 3):

The System namespace is reserved for the .NET Framework.

The Microsoft namespace is reserved for use by Microsoft on .NET libraries that aren't part of the .NET Framework.

The Windows namespace is for Windows 8 WinRT components. These aren't .NET per se, but are projected into .NET for Windows 8 apps.